# How to use 'greater than' on two numpy arrays?

Tags: python

How would I go about comparing these two arrays in Python using 'greater than' > ?

I want to say that if the value of `array[i]` is > the value of `array_two[i]`, then assign 1 to a df (this part isn't important, the condition '>' is).

```
array([6.10486534e-02, 3.20790148e-01, 2.56859660e-01, 2.56859660e-01,
       3.03715386e-01, 3.58806774e-01, 3.76682551e-01, 1.37473505e-01,
       3.58806774e-01, 3.71317921e-04, 3.45058974e-01, 3.45058974e-01,
       8.81391314e-02, 3.20790148e-01, 9.42457566e-03, 8.81391314e-02,
       3.95105724e-01, 5.34622633e-03, 2.08727973e-01, 2.91399310e-03,
       8.81391314e-02, 2.08727973e-01, 2.56859660e-01, 3.85616747e-01,
       1.62975022e-01, 3.58806774e-01, 2.08727973e-01, 2.56859660e-01,
       1.59636395e-02, 3.58806774e-01, 3.85616747e-01, 1.80399797e-01,
       3.76682551e-01, 3.45058974e-01, 8.81391314e-02, 3.58806774e-01,
       1.22269205e-01, 9.42457566e-03, 1.62975022e-01, 3.71317921e-04,
       3.20790148e-01, 3.98205068e-01, 3.20790148e-01, 4.06292733e-02,
       3.95105724e-01, 2.56859660e-01, 3.98205068e-01, 3.45058974e-01,
       8.81391314e-02, 1.00660158e-01])

array([0.3709119 , 0.06697823, 0.35351773, 0.35351773, 0.31950921,
       0.09175405, 0.23816167, 0.01401676, 0.09175405, 0.05914856,
       0.28009387, 0.28009387, 0.39048359, 0.06697823, 0.22254767,
       0.39048359, 0.1964211 , 0.18148102, 0.37939101, 0.14354477,
       0.39048359, 0.37939101, 0.35351773, 0.12191716, 0.39492163,
       0.09175405, 0.37939101, 0.35351773, 0.26470548, 0.09175405,
       0.12191716, 0.02169437, 0.23816167, 0.28009387, 0.39048359,
       0.09175405, 0.3987336 , 0.22254767, 0.39492163, 0.05914856,
       0.06697823, 0.1571276 , 0.06697823, 0.3417329 , 0.1964211 ,
       0.35351773, 0.1571276 , 0.28009387, 0.39048359, 0.00878408])
```

I get this error if I try array > array_two

'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'

Comment: Given the two arrays you showed as `arr1` and `arr2`, then `arr1 > arr2` gives an array of bools as expected, not the error you are reporting. Please post enough code to actually reproduce your error.

Comment: Which index `i` you are talking about? That is the same question the error is complaining about.

Comment: I suppose you used array>array_two in an if-statement? This won't work because you need one single boolean value for that. array>array_two will return an array with an element-by-element comparison of the arrays, so something like [True, True, False, True, .....]. You should specify what it actually is that you want to compare. Is it the size of the arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here is what you want:

```py
df_arr = arr1 > arr2  #Compare two array elements and assign result into new array.
print(df_arr)

df_int_arr = df_arr.astype(int)  #Change the elements True into 1 and False into 0.
print(df_int_arr)
```

And here is the output:

```
[False  True False False False  True  True  True  True False  True  True
 False  True False False  True False False False False False False  True
 False  True False False False  True  True  True  True  True False  True
 False False False False  True  True  True False  True False  True  True
 False  True]

[0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1]
```

You may check my [blog](https://blog.csdn.net/NicholasYTZ/article/details/126913258?spm=1001.2014.3001.5501) to get more information about the Bool index in Chapter Four. And here is the official [guidance](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#indexing-and-slicing) about array indexing and slicing.

Hope this answer helps you~

Answer (score 0):

Should really post code that shows your issue, rather than just two series that doesn't explain what you did to get that error...but in general, something like this might be what u want

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':arr1, 'col2': arr2})
m = df.col1 > df.col2
df['col1']= df.col1.where(m,1)
```

Might also be able to use a choice list. but again - without seeming any code, not exactly sure:

```
df['col1']=np.select([df.col1 > df.col2, df.col1 <= df.col2 ], [1, df.col1])
```